# SVG for CSS generated live

Tags: css, svg, colors, background, server

I was wondering, normal SVGs in CSS are useless because you cannot change their colors, so would it be good idea to use SVGs that are generated by a server script, to which you can pass arguments. Like this

```
icon{
  background: url('http://sitee.com/get-svg.php?name=icon5&color=#c00');
}
```

So you see now I can pass whatever color I want.

But is it a good idea? Because I know that live stylesheets are not: @import "get-stylesheet.php" ...

Comment: I thinks its a good idea. Its like dynamic images.